# Current Financial Year to sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I can't seem to find a straightforward sql without delving into PL SQL for always bringing current financial year in which case 01-04-2015 to sysdate. I want this to always update automatically so when it comes next financial year in 01/04/2016 it will bring whatever is held from that date to whenever the report is being run.

If anyone can please shed some light for me. thanks

sql is:

```
SELECT
  PROPERTY.PRO_MANAGINGCOMPANY_DESCR,
  PROPERTY.PRO_SCHEME_DESCR,
  PROPERTY.PRO_SCHEME,
  SUM(REPAIR_CURRENT.REP_ESTIMATED_COST) as "Estimated Cost",
  nvl(SUM(REPAIR_CURRENT.REP_INVOICED_COST),SUM(REPAIR_CURRENT.REP_ESTIMATED_COST)) as "Estimated Cost Invoiced",
  SUM(REPAIR_CURRENT.REP_INVOICED_COST) as "Invoice Cost",
  to_char(REPAIR_CURRENT.REP_RAISED_DATE,'Mon') as "Month",
  to_number(to_char(to_date(REPAIR_CURRENT.REP_RAISED_DATE,'dd-mon-yy'),'mm')) as "Month No."
FROM
 PROPERTY,
  REPAIR_CURRENT,
  SERVICE_REQUEST
WHERE
  ( SERVICE_REQUEST.SRQ_PRO_REFNO=PROPERTY.PRO_REFNO  )
  AND  ( REPAIR_CURRENT.REP_SRQ_NO=SERVICE_REQUEST.SRQ_NO  )
  AND  
  (
  --PROPERTY.PRO_SCHEME  =   ( '00054'  )
   --AND
   REPAIR_CURRENT.REP_RAISED_DATE  BETWEEN  '01-APR-2015'  AND  sysdate
   AND
   REPAIR_CURRENT.REP_STATUS  <>  'CAN'
  )
GROUP BY
  PROPERTY.PRO_MANAGINGCOMPANY_DESCR,
  PROPERTY.PRO_SCHEME_DESCR,
  PROPERTY.PRO_SCHEME,
  to_char(REPAIR_CURRENT.REP_RAISED_DATE,'Mon'),
  to_number(to_char(to_date(REPAIR_CURRENT.REP_RAISED_DATE,'dd-mon-yy'),'mm'))
```

Comment: Do you want to generate dates from 01-04-2015 to current date?

Comment: Yes for this current financial period it will be 01-04-2015, but I don't want to hardcode this date but was wondering if I can use a function to collect the first date and only the 4th month using some function

Comment: @abs786123 Use a simple `CASE` expression to check the current date and get your desired output. You must provide some sample data and show your desired output. At least create a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Hiya, just added the actual sql I been working on

Comment: @abs786123 Ok, then as I said use `CASE` expression in your filter predicate. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the beginning of the fiscal year for the current date:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('01-04' || CASE 
                            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) > 4 THEN 
                              EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) 
                            ELSE 
                              EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1 
                            END, 'DD-MM-RRRR') FISCAL_YEAR 
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for any date:

```
REPAIR_CURRENT.REP_RAISED_DATE
  BETWEEN Add_Months(Trunc(Add_Months(sysdate,-3),'YYYY'),3)
      AND Sysdate
```

Basically, subtract three months, truncate to the year, and add three months back on.

To just get the financial year for a date, use:

```
Extract(Year from Add_Months(Trunc(Add_Months(sysdate,-3),'YYYY'),3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  datetime >= CASE
                   WHEN SYSDATE < TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YEAR' ) + INTERVAL '3' MONTH 
                   THEN TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YEAR' ) - INTERVAL '9' MONTH
                   ELSE TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YEAR' ) + INTERVAL '3' MONTH
                   END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, the following worked! add_months(trunc(sysdate,'year'),3) AND  sysdate

thank you all for your input :)

Comment: It will not work when the current date is between January and March.

Comment: Please do not add "Thank you" as an answer, instead upvote/accept the answer that helped you. And if you want you can comment to the answer that helped you. The answer section should be only for posting answers. Please go through the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how this site works. All the best!

Comment: You're a little out there. See my answer for a similar but working approach.

Answer (score 0):

> REPAIR_CURRENT.REP_RAISED_DATE  BETWEEN  '01-APR-2015'  AND  sysdate

Firstly, `'01-APR-2015'` is not a **DATE** it is a **string**. You must always use **TO_DATE** along with proper **format model** to **explicitly convert** the string into **DATE**. Or, use the **ANSI Date literal** as you are not concerned with the time portion. It uses a fixed format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

Now, coming to your date arithmetic, you could use a **CASE expression** to evaluate the **financial date** depending on the **year**.

```
REP_RAISED_DATE 
BETWEEN
   CASE
   WHEN 
      SYSDATE <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR'), 3) 
   THEN
      ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') , -9)
   ELSE 
      ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR'), 3)
   END 
AND SYSDATE
```

Basically, `SYSDATE >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR'), 3)` is to check whether **SYSDATE** is greater than `1-APR` of **current yea**r. And, `SYSDATE <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR'), 15)` is to check whether it is between `JAN` and `MARCH` of **next year**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT
  2     CASE
  3       WHEN
  4          SYSDATE <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR'), 3)
  5       THEN
  6          ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') ,-9)
  7       ELSE
  8          ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR'), 3)
  9     END FINANCIAL_YEAR
 10  FROM dual;

FINANCIAL
---------
01-APR-15
```

For date between **JAN** and **MAR** of next year:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2     CASE
  3       WHEN
  4          DATE '2016-02-01' <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(DATE '2016-02-01', 'YEAR'), 3)
  5       THEN
  6          ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(DATE '2016-02-01', 'YEAR') ,-9)
  7       ELSE
  8          ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(DATE '2016-02-01', 'YEAR'), 3)
  9     END FINANCIAL_YEAR
 10  FROM dual;

FINANCIAL
---------
01-APR-15
```

Comment: You want `>=` rather than `>` and the `CASE` does not have an `ELSE` condition so it will never return any results if the current date is between January and March.

Comment: `SYSDATE <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR'), 15)` will always be true and if it is in January - March then you want to subtract 9 months (see [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33939731/1509264)) - if you add 15 months then it will be the start of the FY two years ahead [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/12068).

Comment: You are correct, my testing was incorrect. I checked with hard-coded date in the L.H.S., but, missed it on R.H.S. So, basically, I started writing my SQL in the reverse order of functionality. Corrected now.

Comment: Rather than `WHEN SYSDATE <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR'), 3)`, perhaps `WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) <= 3`

Answer (score 0):

Following SQLreturns start and end date for Financial Year of current date.

```
SELECT 
TO_DATE('01-04' ||   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM add_months(sysdate, -3)),'DD-MM-RRRR') from_dt , 
TO_DATE('31-03' ||   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM add_months(sysdate, 9)),'DD-MM-RRRR') to_dt from dual;
```

For any random date, you can use the following SQL: example for 01-04-2020

```
SELECT 
TO_DATE('01-04' ||   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM add_months(to_date('01-04-2020','DD-MM-RRRR'), -3)),'DD-MM-RRRR') from_dt , 
TO_DATE('31-03' ||   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM add_months(to_date('01-04-2020','DD-MM-RRRR'), 9)),'DD-MM-RRRR') to_dt from dual;
```